# Привязка программы к OC

Tags: c#, защита, .net, авторизация

К каким параметрам OC нужно привязываться, для однозначной идентификации OC.

Нашел в интернете

"`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid`"

"`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductId`"

1-ый незнаю на сколько это уникально и надежно.

2-ой как я понял уникален только если винда лицензионая

Comment: Вам нужно точно понять, какая версия ОС или нужно привязаться к конкретной инсталляции?

Comment: к конкретной инсталляции.

Comment: если нужна обычная, простая защита, просто создайте себе уникальный ключик в реестре\файловой системе. Если нужна понадежнее, сгенерируйте этот ключ, основываясь на серийном номере диска, процессора и ещё чего нибудь.
Если  нужна более-менее нормальная защита - используйте hasp ключ.
Если нужна параноидальная защита - тогда просто  никому не отдавайте свою программу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым простеньким и тривиальным методом для привязки программы к компьютеру считаю генерацию некоего ключа для программы на основе Mac-адреса машины(физический адрес сетевой карты).

Так же можно привязываться к серийному номеру диска, процессора, винчестера и подобного. Но в даном примере я приведу именно на основе мак-адреса.

```
private static string GetMacAdress()
{
    return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(nic => nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        .Select(nic => nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()).FirstOrDefault();             
}

private static string GetNumbersFromMac(string mac)
{
    string tmpDigit = Regex.Replace(mac, @"[^0-9]+", String.Empty);

    string getPositionNumber = string.Empty;

    foreach (char number in tmpDigit)
    {
        getPositionNumber += number * 129 / 258;
    }
    return getPositionNumber;
}

private static string GetMirroredCharsFromMac(string mac)
{
    string tmpLetter = Regex.Replace(mac, @"[^A-Z]+", String.Empty);

    string getMirrored = string.Empty;

    for (int i = tmpLetter.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        getMirrored += (tmpLetter[i - 1]);
    }

    return getMirrored;
}

private static string GetSerial()
{
    var mac = GetMacAdress();

    return GetNumbersFromMac(mac) + GetMirroredCharsFromMac(mac);
}
```

собственно, ты просто на каждом запуске приложения просто сравниваешь свежосгенерированный серийник( при помощи GetSerial() ) с тем, который сохранен апликухой(на диск или в реестр). Если совпадают -- прогу запускать дальше для работы. Если не совпадают -- просить ввести серийник заново.

Не забудь поменять алгоритм генерирования твоего серийника ;)

Comment: Спасибо, луче поздно чем никогда :)